# linking HTML checkbox with element to hide when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I have additional data on an HTML element? For example, I'd like to link a checkbox to HTML I'd like to hide when the checkbox is unchecked. Like the `for` attribute of a `label` element, I want to specify the linkage in markup so I can write a simple, generic script to iterate through all checkboxes and hook up a jQuery event handler to do the hiding/showing.

For example, in this HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="showFoo" />
<div id="foo">
    Some HTML here. Hide this when the checkbox is unchecked.
</div>
```

How can I let my script know that `#showFoo` is related to `#foo`?  Ideally something that doesn't make my HTML non-validating or and doesn't require me to use a specific naming convention for IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `data-[key]` attribute to identify what `#showFoo` should control

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/XNFdm/)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showFoo" data-toggles="foo" />
<div id="foo">
    Some HTML here. Hide this when the checkbox is unchecked.
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#showFoo').change(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('toggles')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. @BNL gave nearly the same answer, but as a tierbreaker I'll accept yours because the code sample handles the hiding case too.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect case for data elements.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showFoo" data-relateddiv="foo" />
```

Then in an event handler on the checkboxs:

```
$('#' + $(this).data("relateddiv")).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "rel" attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showFoo" rel="foo" />

$('#showFoo').click(function(){
  var element_id = $(this).attr('rel');
  var element = $('#'+element_id);
  if(element.is(':hidden')){
    element.slideDown();
    //element.show();
  }
  else{
    element.slideUp();
    //element.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a misuse of the rel attribute. It has a specific list of valid values. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-links Just use data-* attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I use this currently

```
element.each(function(i, e) {  
            var checked = $(e).prop('checked'),
                foo = */Relationship betweeen element and foo*/;
            foo .toggleClass('invisibleClass', checked)
                .toggleClass('visibleClass', !checked);
        });
```

in case you have multiple foos and elements (you have to define the relationship between them first)

Run it on the event of your choice

Comment: What is `*/Relationship betweeen element and foo*/`?

Comment: Well lets say that different checkboxes relate to different divs, in this case foo = $(e).next('div'); for example.

Comment: @Likwid_T - the point of my question is how to define the relationship in the HTML markup so that I don't have to change code if my markup changes. Using data- attributes (see answers below) is a better approach.

Answer (score -1):

Try below

```
if (checkboxIsChecked) {
foo.visibility:visible;
} else {
foo.visibility:hidden;
}
```